# How do I get the same parent result regardless of the order of children being queried? (One to Many)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm building a chat with private rooms. What I'm trying to do is find a room that two users belong too. If there isn't one create one.

**Chat Schema**

```
export const ChatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    participants: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    }],
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

**Query**

```
async findChatBetweenUsers(participantOneId, participantTwoId) {
   return await (await this.chatModel.findOne( { participants: [participantOneId, participantTwoId] } )).populate('participants');
}
```

**Controller**

```
async onJoinRoom(socket: Socket, reciever) {
    const authUser: User = await this.authUser(socket);
    const recievingUser: User = await this.userService.findOne(reciever.username);
    const chat = await this.chatService.findChatBetweenUsers(authUser, recievingUser);

    //Create new chat if doesn't exist
    if(Object.entries(chat).length === 0){
      const newChat = await this.chatService.create(authUser, recievingUser);

      return;
    }

    console.log(chat)
  
}
```

**The problem I'm having**

The order of the `auth` and `receiver` changes depending who is logged in and produces a different query result for chat. For example:

*Example One*

```
const chat = await this.chatService.findChatBetweenUsers('KylesId', 'ChrisId');
```

*Output*

```
"chat" : {
    "_id": 'chatOneId',
    "participants": ['KylesId', 'ChrisId']
}
```

*Example Two*

```
const chat = await this.chatService.findChatBetweenUsers('ChrisId','KylesId');
```

*Output*

```
"chat" : {
    "_id": 'chatTwoId',
    "participants": ['ChrisId', 'KylesId']
}
```

How do I get the same result despite the order of `participants` being queried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [If, instead, you wish to find an array that contains both the elements "red" and "blank", without regard to order or other elements in the array, use the $all operator:](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/)

```
this.chatModel.find({
  participants: {$all: [ObjectId('61ce732e33c7e8a9ad80e151'), ObjectId('61ccf3251b9ba5c8a6ecf2a3')]}
});
```